# Symfony change class name for widget used when generating forms

Tags: forms, symfony1

I have a little question re Symfony and the automatic creation of forms.

Basically what I need to do is to change the class name of the widget which gets used when creating a representation of a database field of type data/time.
Currently its creating a sfWidgetFormDateTime() widget however I would like it to generate a widget from a class which I provide, ie. sfWidgetCustomFormDateTime().

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Just create the new class. Or am I missing something?

Comment: But I will need to set the classname somewhere so that symfony knows when creating the BaseForm not to create the default widget however use mine instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it [Symfony forms: how to change default widget for form generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881379/symfony-forms-how-to-change-default-widget-for-form-generation/2895321#2895321)